# How set default image for prettyPhoto?

Tags: prettyphoto

i using prettyPhoto API.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").live('click',function(){
     api_images = ['photos/actual/47e2c8b5.jpg','photos/actual/22a4e7ab.jpg',,'photos/actual/22a4e7ab.jpg'];
     $.fn.prettyPhoto();
     $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,'','');
   });
});
```

I need to set default image. How set default image in api_images array ?